# pygame Slideshow freezes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

**Context:** 
My current project to automate some of my work is to make a program that will prompt a picture, allow me to type in a name for the picture and then save it in a  new folder on my desktop to be sorted.

**Current situation:**
I've put together a basic slide show app using pygame (Tried Tkinter and I was having problems cycling and allowing for an input so I scrapped it). The below program works great for 2/3 pictures and then it freezes completely and if i move the pygame window, it's bricked again.

**Question:**
Is there any better way of cycling pictures that I'm missing out on? Or is there a way to stop pygame from freezing? I don't think it's memory leak, but I'm only a noob.

All suggestions/help welcome and if you can give any guidance to get to my end goal I would be grateful as heck!

*dave*

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
from os import listdir

location = input()
os.chdir(location)
main = os.listdir()
print(main)

pygame.init()

display_width = 500
display_height = 500

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def car(x,y):
    for image in main:
        print(image)
        carImg = pygame.image.load(image)
        picture = pygame.transform.scale(carImg, (500, 500))
        gameDisplay.blit(picture,(x,y))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(2000)
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

x = (0)
y = (0)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill(blue)
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I looked through your code and couldn't see anything particularly wrong with it... I tried it myself and it worked perfectly for me, kept cycling through photos for as long as I'd allow it.

Comment: Weird.. Thank you Eric. Might be my version of pygame or something.

Comment: So it just freezes, and doesn't write any exception out to the console? Are the images on a network drive? Could be that there is some problem reading them one time or another.

Comment: I was thinking the same.. I tried it with small batches if images on my ssd after as I thought it was because it was coming off my external hdd.. I was going mad thinking it was memory leak or some nonsense.. Ted gave a solid answer, going to re write the whole thing tomorrow (not that there is much, but for me it's a bit) just so I can get my head around the right way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OS thinks the program has frozen since you don't call any functions from the event module in time.

Easy fix is just to put the line `pygame.event.pump()` inside your `car()` function. It would not be a good fix however since you still can't handle any events like closing the window. When you're entering the `car` function you're delaying the program for `2*amount_of_images` seconds, making the program unable to do anything else.

I would do a total refactor of your program (see below). Also, I see you're looking into sentdex pygame tutorial. Make sure to name your variables accordingly to your program so it makes sense. `car(x, y)` is not a good name for displaying images and `main` is not a good name for a list of directories. Try follow PEP8 as well, naming all variables and function with `lowercase_and_underscore` as it's a convention for Python. Sentdex does unfortunately not follow these.

Here's a short example on how I would do it (although there are many other ways to do it):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def load_images():  # This is just a mock-up function.
    images = []
    for i in range(5):
        image = pygame.Surface((500, 360))
        image.fill((51*i, 100, 100))
        images.append(image)
    return images


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    time = 0  # Time to keep track of when to swap images.
    images = load_images()  # List of images.
    image_index = 0  # Current image that's being displayed.
    total_images = len(images)

    while True:

        dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000  # Amount of seconds between each loop.
        time += dt

        if time >= 2:  # If 2 seconds has passed.
            image_index = (image_index + 1) % total_images  # Increment by one and cylce to 0 if greater than 'total_images'
            time = 0  # Reset the time.

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    image_index = (image_index - 1) % total_images
                    time = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    image_index = (image_index + 1) % total_images
                    time = 0

        screen.blit(images[image_index], (110, 60))  # Blit current image at whatever position wanted.
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    main()
```

Comment: Embarrassingly yes I chopped up one of his tutorial programs as it fit the bill.. Thanks a million!! I appreciate it immensely, this puts me on the right tracks.

Comment: Also thank you for the full explanation as to why the window is becoming unresponsive. I was thinking I was loading all 100 images at once into the buffer .. Crazy 3am thoughts huh

Comment: It's not embarrassing, it's common and useful. Just make sure the code make sense for your program. If you feel the answer is answering your question, make sure to mark it as accepted, or leave a comment if there's something I've missed.